# Okta Authentication, Cannot GET /implicit/callback

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth, okta

I'm following this guide https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/ to add authentication to my React App. I've set everything as per the guide, and I get the id token from the demo preview site. The log says the authentication is successful and provides an id token back. [This](http://localhost:8080/implicit/callback#id_token=eyJraWQiOiJ2QzF4MnFMZHRzT0ZYaVA3bzFqb2prR0JPLWUxZkFWYmRMOWNoRHN2TXpnIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.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.Dz_RV99L1bM85dL-bVBi1r5dkbVihxoNhuaycquDLoSIlPKwyJJ7O8S9L0nFyEdOypas-lAPSbY1msPiQpPvWg5rh54267LoWTKYVp4hmo6W7woxOavn-puya2D6eWvXzdx9nIvbpAGkG28LnNhxq9ovRGBzYN6Nq2zQg535PHwR8SeDliLz1NQhzINbc7lK93miEoB5vgMNanLUtBPdCUzam7GHbprxHe4-2XiW4nU01MI9mEVCO2ZsnjibUV1cTrXtDJwnj3AD1WTUJ7HTQXhNAj1hbTknaS6Zt9XdjZzz0tRiqK1zi7zkOfnAt3nJi9sfONEhpC1379QE7FW5CA&access_token=eyJraWQiOiJ2QzF4MnFMZHRzT0ZYaVA3bzFqb2prR0JPLWUxZkFWYmRMOWNoRHN2TXpnIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJ2ZXIiOjEsImp0aSI6IkFULnpONVJYUnBlQ3FhTWM5T21vNTdQYXhTanF1WldLYzV1QXZ5S1lNX2NiVXMiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi00Nzk2MDAub2t0YXByZXZpZXcuY29tL29hdXRoMi9kZWZhdWx0IiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpOi8vZGVmYXVsdCIsImlhdCI6MTUxMDM2MDg0OSwiZXhwIjoxNTEwMzY0NDQ5LCJjaWQiOiIwb2FjdDl0bzdjVXV6emFlSjBoNyIsInVpZCI6IjAwdWN0bHMyYXBUdzhJSGNzMGg3Iiwic2NwIjpbImVtYWlsIiwib3BlbmlkIiwicHJvZmlsZSJdLCJzdWIiOiJzYWxtYWFuQHN5bm9wc3lzLmNvbSJ9.eYe4QjiySoaAlAKS258BoaCrG2fheJw6nJNsRLarrq7Qt1dJ2guePiZri5kdGtk5opJGiLZHLOWLesrGu17akgmdYk5KSGWI_D2qbHaTOyYFkZjSOj4F7_fCZLo8cj8SFOObsL06Tq68OOPDRC4XzuHvbJj79VXYwprjVn7Naqy76BKiZjS4FTj3nIFBFtPv2J0Kw8Say7q8C6zxJzosKm-r5PV3_RUSWEtqRmOC_N3XFc1KefRmwWZ3cQ6WLN9imL3YUOZXW9wWmSfys69SNm5jTxu8FhbzhwElodVXuQQdAqVPCcbaUKwZcldq1S3k21ohCdA3C2cjnxjkRUyQ4A&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=email+openid+profile&state=HLpPaZgQaUJHA14dlcyoOUdd9pvKeXY0VEewNrP1UwvnD4iVdtVPMgGZiie8gEcN) is how the redirect looks like.

On the redirect I get this error: `Cannot GET /implicit/callback` displayed in the browser. Where did I go wrong?

This is how my index.js looks like in React:

```
import { Security, SecureRoute, ImplicitCallback } from '@okta/okta-react';

ReactDOM.render((
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Security issuer={config.issuer}
                  client_id={config.clientId}
                  redirect_uri={config.redirect_uri} >
            <Route path='/' exact={true} component={Full}/>
            <Route path='/implicit/callback' component={ImplicitCallback} />
        </Security>
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

I think it might have something to do with HashRouter and [CoreUI](https://github.com/mrholek/CoreUI-React/tree/master/React_Starter) but I don't know what exactly is the problem as I can get it running with the normal create-react-app template.

Comment: I just went through the steps in the React Quickstart and was able to get everything to work. You can find my project at https://github.com/mraible/okta-react-quickstart.

Comment: I was able to get it up and running using the create-react-app template. For this one I am using CoreUi https://github.com/mrholek/CoreUI-React/tree/master/React_Starter . Can't seem to get it running there. If it's not much work could you have a glance and see if it can be done there. Thanks so much!

Comment: @MattRaible any idea on how to accomplish this using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter?

Comment: could it be an issue with webpack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an issue with Webpack.
Setting `devServer.historyApiFallback: true` and `output.publicPath: '/'` in webpack config fixed the issue.

HashRouter still didn't work, had to use BrowserRouter.